# Why can't a DataMember in WCF return Type?

Tags: wcf

Trying to get this to work, with no luck:

```
[DataMember]
public Type ParameterType { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Web Services, in general, are meant to be cross-platform. What would a Java program do with a System.Type from .NET?

Also, what part of Type would you like to see serialized, and how would you like to see it deserialized?

Comment: I see the point.  I really just need the type name which I can easily pass as a string.

Comment: +1 exactly - anything definable in a XSD schema can be used, but no .NET specifics

Comment: This deflects the question rather than attempting to answer it.

Comment: No, it's the direct answer. You can't return Type because of the nature of web services. Note the questioner apparently felt it not only attempted to answer it, but that it _did_ answer.

Comment: This is incorrect. The nature of web services allows one to transform serializable objects into the appropriate format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx; Just because it is `Type` doesn't make it special. The problem is that the runtime object is actually an internal type, which can't be wired: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/521852e0-d437-4def-848a-ead182a06276. Java could do whatever it wanted with the XML representation of something coming from .NET.

Comment: We're arguing the difference between the nature of web services and their implementation. Yes, an implementation could serialize System.Type (and its schema, remember), and let Java just choke on it. The current implementation of Type will not in fact permit serialization. How fast would that have changed if this were a popular use case?

Comment: The problem I have with this reply is that you are assuming this is a web service.  WCF is not strictly for web services.  I was having this exact same problem in the case where it was two .NET applications communicating with WCF in a closed system.

Answer (score 9):

Any field or property that returns `System.Type` is not serializable using WCF because, at runtime, the actual type of the object is `System.RuntimeType`, which is marked as internal, and thus cannot be automatically serialized by the `DataContractSerializer`, which can only serialize publicly accessible types.

However, you could write an `IXmlSerializer` wrapper around `System.Type` that will pull out the information you intend to transfer.