# DataMember of type Type

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm heading myself a bit into WCF.

I've created a WCF-Service with the following `ServiceContract`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFrameRegistration
{
    [OperationContract]
    void RegisterFrame(Frame frame);

    [OperationContract]
    void UnregisterFrame(string frameName);

    [OperationContract]
    IList<Frame> GetRegisteredFrames();

    [OperationContract]
    Frame GetFrameByName(string frameName);
}
```

The Frame-`DataContract` looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Frame
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FrameName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Type FrameType { get; set; }
}
```

The WCF-Service works fine. It starts and I can access it from my Client-Application.

In my Client-Application I want to call the `RegisterFrame`-Method. Therefor I use the following code:

```
FrameRegistrationClient client = new FrameRegistrationClient();
client.RegisterFrame(new Frame
{
    Name = "Login",
    Type = typeof(LoginWindow)
});
```

`LoginWindow` is a WPF-Window.

The call to RegisterFrame throws an exception which looks something like:

> The type 'System.RuntimeType' with the datacontractname
>   'RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' was not
>   expected. Try to use a DataContractResolver or add all unknown types
>   to the static list of the known types. ...

Not sure if the exception-message is correct. I translated it from german.

How can I send the `FrameType` as `Type` to my client?

Comment: You can use a string representing the type name instead.

Comment: I already thought about that. But is there no way to send the type from the service to the client?

Comment: Does your service *know* the type? Is a assembly loaded that implements `LoginWindow` *on the service side*?

Comment: No, the only the client knows the Window. The service just have to store it for me, so that another application can get it from it

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1110773/1054649

Comment: It should probably be handled manually, meaning that you can serialize the `Type` object on your own, then send it over the service, then deserialize it back to the `Type` class again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.Type type cannot be serialized like that. You could add a string property, like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Frame
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FrameName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FrameTypeName
    {
        get
        {
            // or FrameType.FullName, depends on compatibility between client & server
            return FrameType != null ? FrameType.AssemblyQualifiedName : null;
        }
        set
        {
            FrameType = value != null ? Type.GetType(value, true) : null;
        }
    }

    // don't serialize this one
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Type FrameType { get; set; }
}
```